# Add attribute based on condition from onClick React js

Tags: reactjs, button

I want to stop current page from redirect if condition is false because I want to show an error message on the same page if condition fails and redirect to another page if condition is correct. How can I do that?

```
<Button fullWidth color="primary" onClick={function  (){

if(condition) redirect to x;
else
redirect to y;

}} /*to={setUrl}*/>
<Trans>text</Trans> 
</Button>
```

Comment: What do you mean with you want to stop the redirect?
Basically React works by setting the state and in the new rendering you set the attributes from the current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using react router, you can use, `this.props.history.push('url')` to redirect to a url and implement your notification display in the `showNotification()`;

```
<Button fullWidth color="primary" onClick={()=>{

if(condition) this.props.push('/home');
else
this.showNotification();

}}/>
<Trans>text</Trans> 
</Button>
```